# package does not exist error - cannot find packages within directory

Tags: java, selenium, import

I have a .java file (built by another dev) that I am running from the command line to perform some Selenium tests.

```
SeleniumsTests.java
/lib (directory of dependencies)
```

When I try to run this java file direct from the terminal it returns a series of errors related to packages it is unable to find saved in the lib directory.

```
SeleniumsTestsjava:21: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Assert;
            ^
SeleniumsTests.java:22: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                      ^
SeleniumsTests.java:23: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
                      ^
SeleniumsTests.java:24: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

// other similar related errors
```

Within the .java itself I can see the link to these within the following imports but I cannot see how it links to the corresponding folder 'lib' - what do I do to reflect these packages within this lib directory

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

Comment: u need to add the libs with classpath

Answer (score 1):

For every java program if its depends on external jar files you have to add them into java classpath. First google for the external jar, like `download jar org.openqa.selenium and org.junit` and download them from maven site and add them to your java class path and compile with `javac` and run like `java -classpath "class-path" javaclassfileNamewithoutextension` (without the extension of .class):-